# Redirect only when on a specific domain

Tags: redirect

I got the domains example.com and example.se and I'm discontinuing the example.com domain soon so i want some kind of redirect.

Both domains point to the same directory on my web hotel so all files are the same on both domains.

What are the best way to make people (and google) access the example.se domain intead of example.com?

The webserver runs Apache and i got limited control (shared hosting).

Comment: what kind of web server you using? Do you have full control on the web server or just shared hosting?

Comment: What web server are you on? Apache? IIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.se$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.se/$0 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

The [301 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is for permanent redirections.

Comment: Can I make all subdirectorys redirect aswell?
(example.com/dir/ to example.se/dir/)

Comment: Apperently not enough, sorry for that... Thanks :)